# Lagom Kafka Unexpected Close Error

Tags: apache-kafka, lagom

In Lagom Dev Enviornment, after starting Kafka using lagomKafkaStart

sometimes it shows KafkaServer Closed Unexpectedly, after that i need to run clean command to again get it running.

Please suggest is this the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if you forcibly shut down sbt and the ZooKeeper data becomes corrupted.

Other than running the clean command, you can manually delete the `target/lagom-dynamic-projects/lagom-internal-meta-project-kafka/` directory.

This will clear your local data from Kafka, but not from any other database (Cassandra or RDBMS). If you are using Lagom's message broker API, it will automatically repopulate the Kafka topic from the source database when you restart your service.

Comment: thanks @timmoore , will this clear my local data , or what impact running the clean command has on my setup

Comment: @techagrammer I edited the answer to answer your follow up question.